# Is there a comma after "As of today"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> As of today(?) I'm a student of a prestigious university.

Should there be a comma after "As of today"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A significant proportion of the examples of the use of this expression (at the beginning of a sentence) on the web separate it from what follows with a comma. So if you must use it, then most people will expect it to be followed by a comma.

Why are you using it? What is wrong with "Today I am ..." or "Now I am ..." or even "Currrently, I am ..."?

Comment: To emphasize the date in a jokingly serious way. I hope it does so.